# Minizinc Model pickup and delivery in a problem similar to Vehicle Route Problem

Tags: constraint-programming, declarative, minizinc

I am new to Minizinc and I want to adjust a VRM problem that I have found [here](https://github.com/jlhonora/vrp-minizinc/blob/master/vrptw.mzn).

I have to add a couple of functionalities but the one with which I am really struggling is dependencies between pickup and deliveries services. Some nodes (the delivery nodes) have to be visited only after some other nodes were visited previously (the pick up nodes).

I was thinking to add an input for the precendence like this:

```
array[1..n_orders div 2, 1..2] of int: precedences = [| 1, 3 | 2, 4 | 5, 10 | 7, 8 | 6, 9 |];
```

Basically, it says that node 3 has to be visit after node 1, node 4 after node 2 and so on...

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the basic precedence can be established by constraining

```
constraint forall(i in index_set1of2(precedences)) (
    DepartureTimes[precedences[i,1]] < DepartureTimes[precedences[i,2]]
)
```